# How to plot an histogram or bar animation with matplotlib ArtistAnimation?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create histogram animation that stacks up samples one by one.
I thought the following code would work, but it doesn't.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import ArtistAnimation

ims = []
fig = plt.figure()
x =[1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,9,9,10]

for i in range(len(x)):
    img = plt.hist(x[:i])
    ims.append(img)

ani = ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=100)
plt.show()
```

Changing plt.hist to plt.plot shows animation. Don't know what the difference is.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Start with this and modify: http://omz-software.com/pythonista/matplotlib/examples/animation/dynamic_image2.html

Comment: This is probably the same reason: http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Problem-animating-a-histogram-and-movie-at-the-same-time-td48066.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plt.hist` does not return an artist but a tuple with binning results and the artist (see [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html)).

This is also discussed in [this thread](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Problem-animating-a-histogram-and-movie-at-the-same-time-td48066.html) in the Matplotlib mailing list:

> ArtistAnimation expects to be given a list of lists (or tuples), where
>   the inner collection contains all of the artists that should be
>   rendered for a given frame. In the case of bar, it returns a
>   BarCollection object (which I just learned), is a subclass of tuple.
>   This explains why it works (by itself), when directly appended to the
>   list given to ArtistAnimation; the BarCollection acts as the
>   collection of artists that ArtistAnimation is expecting. In the case
>   of the second example, ArtistAnimation is being given a
>   list([BarCollection, Image]); because BarCollection isn't actually an
>   Artist, it causes the problem.

The problem mentioned there uses different plot types:

```
im1 = ax1.imshow(f(xm, ym), aspect='equal', animated=True)
im2 = ax2.bar(xx, a, width=0.9*(b[1]-b[0]), color='C1')
```

and the solution in that case is

```
ims.append([im1] + list(im2))
```

The way to make this work in your case is to look at the return values of `plt.hist` and find out where the artists are being returned and put them in the correct list of lists format.

This works:

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()

# ims is a list of lists, each row is a list of artists to draw in the
# current frame; here we are just animating one artist, the image, in
# each frame
ims = []

for i in range(60):

    # hist returns a tuple with two binning results and then the artist (patches)
    n, bins, patches = plt.hist((np.random.rand(10),))

    # since patches is already a list we can just append it
    ims.append(patches)

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=50, blit=True,
    repeat_delay=1000,)

plt.show()
```